# Add more items to xml file using iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, ios

Hi some body help me I am using one xmlfile like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<MangoUserDataFile>
    <Device>iPad</Device>
    <Version>3.0</Version>
        <UserName>XYZ</UserName>
        <UserType>Admin</UserType>  
        <Module>TabView</Module>    
        <tab id="1">
        <item>
                  <name>Admin</name>
                  <value>WebView</value>
                  <image>20</image>
               </item>
        </tab>
</MangoUserDataFile>
```

I want to add more items in this xmlfile from IPad

For exmaple, I am creating some textfields called:

`nametextfiled`, `valuetextfiels`, `imagetextfield`

... and once I enter the value in these textfields and click to submit at that time another items should be created in these XML File

Can some body give me any ideas on this how we add another item in xmlfile from IPad.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you should rewrite all the elements into a new XML file, and try to replace the old XML file with the new one.

Writing can be done using these classes:

```
//
//  XMLBuilder.h
//  TaxiSharing
//
//  Created by Erle on 02.07.09.
//  Copyright 2009 University of Duisburg-Essen,
//  Institute of Computer Science and Business Computer Science
//  Group for Pervasive Computing and User Interface Engineering 
//   All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface XMLBuilder : NSObject {
    NSMutableString *XMLString;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableString *XMLString;

-(void)addTagToXML:(NSString *)tag withValue:(NSString *)value;
-(void)addSelfClosedTag:(NSString *)tag withInnerValueTitle:(NSString *)innerValueTitle andValue:(NSString *)value;
-(void)addSelfClosedTag:(NSString *)tag withInnerString:(NSString *)innerString;
-(void)addSingleTag:(NSString *)tag withInnerString:(NSString *)innerString;
-(void)addSingleValue:(NSString *)value;
-(void)addSingleTag:(NSString *)tag;
-(void)endSingleTag:(NSString *)tag;
-(void)closeXML;

@end

//
//  XMLBuilder.m
//  TaxiSharing
//
//  Created by Erle on 02.07.09.
//  Copyright 2009 University of Duisburg-Essen,
//  Institute of Computer Science and Business Computer Science
//  Group for Pervasive Computing and User Interface Engineering 
//   All rights reserved.
//

#import "XMLBuilder.h"


@implementation XMLBuilder

@synthesize XMLString;

-(id)init{
    [super init];
    XMLString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> \n"];
    return self;
}

-(void)addTagToXML:(NSString *)tag withValue:(NSString *)value{
    [XMLString appendFormat:@"<%@>%@</%@> \n",tag,value,tag];
}

-(void)addSelfClosedTag:(NSString *)tag withInnerValueTitle:(NSString *)innerValueTitle andValue:(NSString *)value{
    [XMLString appendFormat:@"<%@ %@=%@ /> \n",tag,innerValueTitle,value];
}

-(void)addSelfClosedTag:(NSString *)tag withInnerString:(NSString *)innerString{
    [XMLString appendFormat:@"<%@ %@ /> \n",tag,innerString];
}

-(void)addSingleTag:(NSString *)tag withInnerString:(NSString *)innerString{
    [XMLString appendFormat:@"<%@ %@ > \n",tag,innerString];
}
-(void)addSingleValue:(NSString *)value{
    [XMLString appendFormat:@"%@ \n",value];
}

-(void)addSingleTag:(NSString *)tag{
    [XMLString appendFormat:@"<%@> \n",tag];
}

-(void)endSingleTag:(NSString *)tag{
    [XMLString appendFormat:@"</%@> \n",tag];
}

-(void)closeXML{
    [XMLString appendFormat:@"\n"];
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
    [XMLString release];
}
@end
```

I found this code on http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-requests/34645-how-create-xml-file-dynamically.html.

Comment: Basically my requirement is whenever we enter the name,value ,image in the textfields and click to submit at that time its add to xmlfile if you have any code related all please send me so that I can used this one.OR please tell me how to update old xml file to new xml file .my requirement is to add item in xmlfile when i click the submit button then the value i enter in nametextfield will update in name,valuetextfield will update as value and image textfield will update as image.Please give me any idea how to do. Thanks