# Manipulating files in XML in iOS

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, xml-parsing, xsd

I want to know if possible to manipulate XML as this way in iOS.

1. Create the XML from nothing.
2. Insert custom tags and info in an order.

Example:

- creating xml in memory like an array or dictionary
- insert tag `<test></test>`
- insert tag `<field1>some</field1>` inside `<test />`
- insert tag `<field2>some</field2>` after `<field1 />`
- insert tag `<field12>some</field>` inside `<field2 />`
- close xml and save to NSDocuments

Thanks

Comment: Save to NSDocuments? I think you mean the app document directory.

Comment: I found this and I think is what I want if this works... xD http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660689/add-more-items-to-xml-file-using-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use plist files which are essentially xmls.
You can directly write/read plist files to/from NSArray or NSDictionary.

Check the [Plist Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: But I want to make it compatible with an android app and a php script... so plist didn't work somethings because they had to adapt to me, and I have to adapt to a xml schema.